# iframe white flash

Tags: iframe

I have a left-hand navigation within my iFrame, with two items, switching between two pages. Sometimes there's a white flash, sometimes there isn't.

Some of the methods I've tried so far:

```
<iframe style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility = 'visible';">
```

Did not do the trick.

```
jQuery('#jobs-frame').load(function(){
    $(this).show();
});

jQuery('#primary a').click(function(){ 
    //alert('hello');
    jQuery('#jobs-frame').hide();
});
```

Also did not do the trick.
Any other method I've tried out has appeared to be outdated. What's puzzling me is that these above 2 solutions have many comments/feedback saying they work, but in Chrome - the only browser I've tested this in so far - I am still having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with iframes that were dynamically generated.  On Chrome, toggling `visibility` removed the white flash, but there was still flickering.  On Safari, toggling `display` actually introduced a related iframe repaint bug.

What ended up working for me was toggling `opacity`:

```
<iframe style="opacity: 0;" onload="this.style.opacity = 1;">`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the 'white flash', don't navigate using links to HTML pages, but put both pages into 2 `<div>`s and switch between them (this also allows for pretty animations).

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier offers a very elegant solution that is better than putting `visibility` attributes. He has a [good explanation](https://css-tricks.com/prevent-white-flash-iframe/) why it is better but the short answer is "users with JavaScript turned off will never see that iframe" if you use `visibility`.

Here is his code. Put it in your `<head>` and make sure you combine the `window.onload` function with yours, if you already have one.

```
(function () {    
    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] || 
              document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    div.innerHTML = '&shy;<style> iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style>';

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);

    window.onload = function() {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }        
})();
```

It works by inserting a CSS on the page, which makes all iframes invisible, so the whiteflash is not visible as well. When the window loads, the CSS is removed and all is well.

*We should all thank him for this nice article, not me :).*

Answer (score -1):

just give `style="background-color: #000000;"` to html tag